# Can I use SDK platform image resources legitimately in my App?

Tags: android, licensing, adt

I was wondering if someone could tell me definitively if you are allowed to use the various platform resources found in the adt bundle folder for the various android API versions

%Program Files%\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platforms\sdk

Specifically I want to use some icon resources. I see other developers use these resources in their apps. I'd like to know if this strictly allowed or not?

Comment: directly copy drawable and use in your code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the folder, I am seeing a "NOTICE.txt" that says

```
"Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License."
```

So, if you comply with it, then you can.

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed and even recommanded ;-)

> Action bar icons are graphic buttons that represent the most important actions people can take within your app. Each one should
>   employ a simple metaphor representing a single concept that most
>   people can grasp at a glance.
>
> Pre-defined glyphs should be used for certain common actions such as
>   "refresh" and "share." The download link below provides a package with
>   icons that are scaled for various screen densities and are suitable
>   for use with the Holo Light and Holo Dark themes. The package also
>   includes unstyled icons that you can modify to match your theme, in
>   addition to Adobe® Illustrator® source files for further
>   customization.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

You can download a pack with source files [here](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not only legal, but you're also **encouraged** to use them.

Anyway, you can avoid copying those files in your drawable folders, since they are already available when you use a syntax like: **android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save**